# How do I calculate the hex value for the bandwidth setting on an SX126x?

Tags: rf, sx126x

I am programming a [SX126x IC](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/761/SEMT_S_A0008596633_1-2575829.pdf) in GFSK modulation.

I am trying to figure out if there is a formula to calculate the bandwidth.

I understand that the BW can be programmable from ~4 to 500kHz.

In the datasheet, it shows me some fixed bandwidth values (they also show the variables from their own library, I am making my library) and I lined them up to try and understand what the formula might be:

[image: sx126x bandwidth]

The decimal values range (and all the numbers are here) from 9 to 31. I colored the "pattern."

Is there any mention of the formula for the BW in the datasheet so I can implement it? I think maybe there is a standard formula in the RF world that I am not aware of, and that might be the reason they don't mention it in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that hardcoding the table is the most appropriate way.
But for reference, the formula appears to be approximately:

- Bits 0-2 of register value: **exponent**
- Bits 3-4 of register value: **divider**

**BW = 3.736 MHz / ((divider + 3) * 2<sup>exponent</sup>)**

Comment: Too lazy to validate that now. I will judge you another day. But have my upvote for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to hard-code the BW setting(s). That's how they do it in the [official library](https://github.com/Lora-net/sx126x_driver/tree/master) as well:

[image: sx126x bandwidth]